# Date Time formatting

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I am selecting date in datepicker and getting something like this is edittext: `13/12/2014` but i have to show like this: `13 Dec 2014`

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

public EditText activity_edittext;

public DatePickerFragment(EditText edit_text) {
    activity_edittext = edit_text;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        activity_edittext.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/" + String.valueOf(month + 1 ) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
    }
}
```

In a same way using time picker, i am getting value like this: `21:12` and i have to show something like this: `9:12 pm`

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        public EditText activity_edittext;

        public TimePickerFragment(EditText edit_text)
        {
            activity_edittext = edit_text;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            activity_edittext.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format your Date. As you can form your Date as `13 Dec 2014` from `13/12/2014` by using `dd MMM yyyy` format.

```
try {

    String dateString = String.valueOf(day) + "/" + String.valueOf(month + 1 ) + "/" + String.valueOf(year);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    String formatedDate = sdf.format(date);

} catch (Exception e) {}
```

OR, simply you can convert month of your Date using `DateFormatSymbols` as below

```
String month = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1];
```

And format your Time as `9:12 pm` with `hh:mm a` format as below

```
try {

    String timeString = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date time = sdf.parse(timeString);

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    String formatedTime = sdf.format(time);

} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: thanks, i tapped as useful, i used your solution for DatePicker and Mystic Magic's solution for Time Picker and now i am confuse one to accept

Comment: the answer seemed to you as better, you can checked that as accepted.

Comment: this is the better answer since it works only with the API, without any hard- coded strings, also it depends on the system locale, so it is multilanguage

Answer (score 1):

You are setting wrongly. You need to check which month is it, and based on it you will need to add its Text.

Try this for setting date:

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    String month_name="";
    switch(month) {
        case Calendar.JANUARY:
            month_name = "JAN";
        break;
        case Calendar.FEBRUARY:
            month_name = "FEB";

        case Calendar.MARCH:
            month_name = "MAR";
        break;
        case Calendar.APRIL:
            month_name = "APR";

        case Calendar.MAY:
            month_name = "MAY";
        break;
        case Calendar.JUNE:
            month_name = "JUN";

        case Calendar.JULY:
            month_name = "JUL";

        case Calendar.AUGUST:
            month_name = "AUG";
        break;
        case Calendar.SEPTEMBER:
            month_name = "SEP";
        case Calendar.OCTOBER:
            month_name = "OCT";
        break;
        case Calendar.NOVEMBER:
            month_name = "NOV";
        break;
        case Calendar.DECEMBER:
            month_name = "DEC";    
        break;
    }
    activity_edittext.setText(String.valueOf(day) + " " + month_name + " " + String.valueOf(year));
}
```

For setting time in 12 hour format, you will need to check its time and set text accordingly:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    String hour = "";
    String meridiem = "";
    Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
    datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
        meridiem = "AM";
    else if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
        meridiem = "PM";

    hour = (datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0) ?"12":String.valueOf(datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    activity_edittext.setText(hour + ":" + String.valueOf(minute) + " " + meridiem);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, i tapped as useful, i used your solution for TimePicker and Hamid Shatu's solution for Date Picker and now i am confuse one to accept

Comment: @Sun that's okay :) You can accept Hamid's answer.. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd M yyyy", Locale.getDefault ());
Date date = null;
try {
    date = formatter.parse("your date here");
} catch (Exception e) { }
```